# Optimizing Queries while being limited on the number of Indexes I can use

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that involves a join on three tables. Let these tables be A, B and C. A and C have a primary key and they are joined through an equi-join to B using 2 foreign keys that B has. The optimal indexing strategy would be to use 4 indexes on all 4 keys. However I am constrained on the number of indexes I can build..(for reasons I had rather not go into).

The size of tables is such that B has 6 million rows. A has 10 thousand and C has 100 thousand rows.

My question is whether I should build separate indexes on both foreign keys of B(to table A and table C) or if I would benefit by creating a composite index on foreign keys of table B.

The size of an index is not a major issue. However the number of indexes have to be minimized while retaining performance.  There are also some filter conditions on attributes of A , B and C.

**Note:** The database is PostgreSQL 12 and is limited in shared_buffer_space.

**Edit**
The Query Structure is

```
SELECT A.a1, A.a2, B.b1, B.b2, C.c1, C.c2 
FROM 
   A INNER JOIN B ON A.a3=B.b3 AND A.a5 = <some value> AND B.b6 = <some value>
     INNER JOIN C ON B.b4=C.c4 AND C.c7 = <some value> AND C.c8 = <some other value>;
```

I was wondering what other optimizations might I do to Improve query performance including but not limited to Indexing and tuning the Performance Optimizer. 
The joins are all on integers.

Comment: Please show the query that you want to optimize.  Your description is not quite as clear as you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query looks like:

```
select . . .
from b join
     a
     on a.a_id = b.a_id join
     c
     on c.c_id = b.c_id
```

Then no additional indexes are really necessary.  The primary key indexes on `a` and `c` are sufficient.

Comment: Wouldnt foreign key indexes on B help?

Comment: @user12984287 . . . I don't know what a "foreign key index" really means.  Under some circumstances, having indexes on the columns used for foreign keys could help.  That would be more the case if you were filtering on those columns.

Comment: By Foreign Key Index I mean indexes on the foreign key column.

Comment: @user12984287 . . . That would help if you were filtering on that column or on columns in the reference table.  You have no filters, so I don't think it would be a big help in this case.